# How to prevent the pink box error message when Facebook Page is wrong?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I'm developing a new page where it renders Facebook's Like Box.

When the fanpage URL submited by the user is wrong, it loads a red/pink box with this message:

The `href` parameter must reference a valid Facebook page, but "https://www.facebook.com/x" is not a valid Facebook page.

Sometimes, it doesn't load.

Anyway, what I want to know is: is there a way to prevent this error message to be loaded when URL is wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the purpose of the error is to let you know the parameters are incorrect - there's no way to load the Like Box with invalid parameters but without the error message